# Method with user input not returning first input

Tags: java, while-loop

I am having trouble with this particular method. The method is being used to ask the user which course pre-requisites they have. When I call on the method later in my program to return the values entered by the user, the program completely skips the first input.

For example, if the user entered "CS 120, CS 125, CIS 130", the program only displays "CS 125, CS 130".

Thanks for your help!

```
//This method gathers the user's course pre-requisites
   public static String getPreReqs(String preReqs, String list){
    int i = 1;  
    System.out.print("List pre-requisite #1(enter done, if finished entering pre-requisites)? ");
    preReqs = console.nextLine();

    list += preReqs;
    console.nextLine();
    while(!preReqs.equalsIgnoreCase("done")){
      i++;
      list += preReqs + " ";
      System.out.print("List pre-requisite #" + i + "(enter done, if finished entering pre-requisites)? ");
      preReqs = console.nextLine();
      }
      return list;
      }//ends getPreReqs method
```

Comment: it seems those 2 lines before the `while` aren't necessary `list += preReqs;` `console.nextLine();` did you try to remove them?

Comment: This could be solved in a much more logical fashion. Have you considered storing the prereqs in a data structure, then iterating through that later to print them?

Comment: @shahaf I tried that and it  still omitted the first user input.

Comment: @CHenry I am new to Java and have not learned how to implement data structures such as arrays yet.

Comment: @Jared can you provide the input? it is one pre requisites per line, right?

Comment: @shahaf it is actually concatenated. The output is "Pre-requisites are: ". It should then print all of the user input when the method is called. However, it is skipping whatever the user enters first, but print everything after.

Answer (score 0):

didn't understand your use case and input, so did something I think should be in the right direction

```
public static String getPreReqs(){
    int i = 1;
    Scanner console =  new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append("Pre-requisites are: ");
    while (true){
        System.out.print("List pre-requisite #"+ i +"(enter done, if finished entering pre-requisites)? ");
        String preReqs = console.nextLine();

        if (preReqs.toLowerCase().equals("done"))
            break;

        result.append(preReqs).append(" ");
        i += 1;
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

I used `StringBuilder` cause it's provide better performance when concatenating  strings

let me know how far away I am from your use-case and I'll try to adjust my solution